# Is it true that $\inf(A+B)\leq \inf(A) + b$?

Tags: real-analysis

Claim: For any $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$,  $\inf(A+B)\leq \inf(A) + b$ for all $b\in B$.

*Proof:* Suppose for a contradiction, there exists $b\in B$ with $\inf(A+B)-b>\inf(A)$. Then $\forall a\in A$, $a=(a+b)-b\geq \inf(A+B)-b > \inf(A)$. Take $A=[0,1]$, then $0\in A$ and $0=\inf(A)$, but $0\ngtr 0$, thus contradiction.

But I feel like this proof is wrong?

Comment: You are right to be skeptical! Unfortunately, your proof is completely wrong. You've only shown one very particular example, which is never enough to prove a statement of the form "For all $A$ ..."

Comment: You have to prove $a>\inf (A)$ is not true for general case, instead your specific case where $A=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is not conclusive because you have realized to a particular example.

Rather, the proof can go by this way: For any $b\in B$ and $a\in A$, we have $a+b\geq\inf(A+B)$ and hence $a\geq\inf(A+B)-b$, since this expression is valid for all $a\in A$, we have $\inf A\geq\inf(A+B)-b$, move $b$ to the left-sided, we are done.